# A sequence with near constant auto-correlation?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, functional-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Suppose
$$
x[n]=
\begin{cases}
x_n &, n \in P\\
0  &, n \notin P
\end{cases}
$$
where $P \subset \{0,1, \cdots,N-1 \}$ and $|P|=K$ and $x_n \geq 0$.

for this sequence these equations hold:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} x[n]x[((n+m))_N] = A >0 , \qquad n= 1,\cdots,N-1
$$
i.e. it's circular auto-correlation is a positive constant

I think it is useful to note that this is resulted from these equalities :
$$
|X[1]|=||X[2]|=\cdots=|X[N-1]|
$$
where 
$$ 
X[k] = DFT\{x[n]\} 
$$

**I want to find all possible $x_n$'s for a given set $P$.**

If we assume $$
x[n]=
\begin{cases}
1 &, n \in P\\
0  &, n \notin P
\end{cases}
$$
Then it holds only when P is a cyclic difference set.

But how about the general case? Is there any other conditions that this is possible?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Yes. In other words, $P$ is support of $x[n]$.

Comment: Ok, so you have also fixed $P$, then you want to find the $\mathbf{x}$, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, You are right. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mahdi, like one of your previous questions, here also, I have this observation, but probably you've already made it, that if $$x[n]\xrightarrow{DFT} X[k]$$ then, you have $$|X[k]|=\sqrt{A}\ \forall k\in \{1,\cdots\ N-1\}$$ and $$X[k]=\sum_{n\in P}x_n w^{kn}$$ where $w=\exp(-i2\pi/N)$

Another observation.

Let the DFT matrix be $$D=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & w & w^2& \cdots & w^{N-1}\\
1 & w^2 & w^4& \cdots & w^{2(N-1)}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & w^{N-1} & w^{2(N-1)} & \cdots & w^{(N-1)(N-1)}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{v_0} & \mathbf{v_1} & \mathbf{v_2} & \cdots & \mathbf{v_{N-1}}\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ where
 $$\mathbf{v_n}=
[1 \quad w^n \quad  w^{2n} \quad  \cdots \quad  w^{(N-1)n}]^T$$ Let $\mathbf{x}$ be the vector with $x_n=0\ \forall n\notin P$. Then the constraints on the magnitudes of $X[k]$ can be rewritten as $$\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{v_i}\mathbf{v_i}^{\dagger}\mathbf{x}=A$$ for $ i=\{0,1,2,\cdots,\ N-1\}$ (For the time being I'm assuming $\sum_{n\in P}x_n=\sqrt{A}$).

So, basically, we want the solution of this set of simultaneous **non-linear** equations.

I think, [this](http://folk.uib.no/ssu029/Pdf_file/Broyden65.pdf) will be helpful in solving these equations.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi, you'll not get that, note that in the equations the matrix in between is $\mathbf{v_i}\mathbf{v_i}^{\dagger}$ which will be the all $1$ matrix for $i=0$.

Comment: No. I have written $v_i v_i^{\dagger}$. Maybe my $\dagger$ is not clearly visible, is it?

Comment: Yes got it. Thank you very much. Is there analytic solution for this system of equations? Or I must solve it using numerical methods?

Comment: I don't know, I'm still searching for that :-P Maybe you can ask this question here in MSE, see what people say.

Comment: Through simulations I reached the result that it by assumption of $\sum_{n\in P}x_n=\sqrt{A}$ some solutions will not be available anymore and it drop out some solutions!

Comment: Maybe you can change it then, I mean the constant $\sqrt{A}$. Also, now, since you have this representation, you can also vary the constants in the RHS and see what happens.